# Create encryption that I cannot decrypt until a later date

Tags: encryption

I am looking for a way to achieve something similar to a "time chest", which is similar to a "time bomb".

The motivation for this came from first installing a productivity enhancing extension for chrome that blocks social media sites (e.g. facebook, insta, etc). The problem with these extensions is that I've found it's too easy to disable the extension. To make this more difficult, I would like to password protect the disable feature. However, this accomplishes nothing if I know what the password is. The easiest solution to the problem I am facing is to simply ask a friend in real life to create a password, and not tell me for X duration of time, but I am now curious if this is possible with an encryption algorithm/trick instead.

For example, I input the string "apples" and the algorithm encodes it into some long and convoluted output "sha1-output-apples". Now, I will set the password for the extension's disable feature to "sha1-output-apples", and then clear my clipboard. I would then also like to make it such that if I try to encode "apples" again, it will give me different outputs until a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/482.pdf

Comment: you could use an "email reminder service" to keep your password until a specified time, when it emails you the password. a sha would be a decent way of making an unmemorable password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might achieve what you want to do using a secure device like JavaCard and NTP with public key decryption.

Java card is a device that you can put tiny code in it and run the code via card reader.data stored in the device is encrypted(How secure it is is depends on the device specification).

NTP proves the time and Javacard(or any other similar device) secures data until the time comes.

at the first, You have to pick a trustable NTP server then put data you want to encrypt, the NTP public key and a program that returns the data only if the NTP response's time meets your requirement and valid signature are given to a Javacard.

You have to achieve one of the following to steal the data before the x day.

- Break JavaCard security
- Steal the NTP's private key or crack the server

If these are difficult enough for your purpose, you can use this as long as the NTP server changes key or stop servicing.

Maybe proof of work based Blockchain might be used instead of NTP. valid list of blockheader works like a non-accurate clock.You still have to figure it out how to validate difficulty changes though.